# change iis localhost from C: to D:

Tags: iis, localhost

i am using php in iis in our windows R2 server, the default localhost path is `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` and i want to change it to D for the reason that C might be full.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look [here](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/a59a2665-9078-43ef-8b5a-5bf9bcacc95e.mspx?mfr=true) for IIS6:

> To change the home directory of a Web site using IIS Manager
>
> 1. In IIS Manager, expand the local computer, expand the Web Sites directory, right-click the Web site you wish to change, and click
>    Stop.
> 2. Use Windows Explorer, to rename the LocalDrive:\Inetpub\Wwwroot directory to the name of your choice. Alternatively, you can copy the
>    entire \Wwwroot directory tree to a new location.
> 3. In IIS Manager, right-click your Web site, and click Properties.
> 4. Click the Home Directory tab, and under The content for this resource should come from, click A directory located on this computer,
>    A share located on another computer, or A redirection to a URL,
>    depending on where your home directory is located.
> 5. In the Local path box, type the path name, share name, or URL of your directory.
>
> Note    If you select a directory on a network share, you might need
> to enter a user name and password to access the resource.
> IUSR_computername is the default account used if another account is
> not specified. If you use an account with administration credentials
> on the server, clients can gain access to server operations. This
> seriously jeopardizes the security of your network. For more
> information on security user rights see, "Security Best Practices" in
> Help and Support Center for Windows Server 2003.
>
> 6. In IIS Manager, expand the Web Sites folder, right-click the Web site you just changed, and click Start.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do.... Just do below steps:

```
  1. Open IIS Manager. For information about opening IIS Manager, 
     see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7).
  2. In the Connections pane, expand the Sites node in the tree, and 
     then click to select the site in which you want to change the physical path 
     for virtual directory content.
  3. In the Actions pane, click View Virtual Directories.
  4. From the Virtual Directories page, select a virtual directory in the list.
  5. In the Actions pane, click Basic Settings.
  6. In the Physical path box, change the path of the virtual directory content.
  7. Click OK.
```